# Computer can only connect to certain WiFi networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I work at my university assisting students with various computer issues. In this case, I have a student who connected to our network (we have a guest network and our regular network which requires MAC-address registration on our website). Things work perfectly fine when we connect his computer to our network, however the computer completely refuses to connect to literally any other wireless networks.

I have booted into safemode, same results.. I even booted into Linux running off of a USB drive, and still ran into the same results. At that point my mind was promptly blown so I turn to you guys.

Any advice???

Comment: What messages or error's do you see?

Comment: When attempting to connect we'll get the prompt to enter a passkey.  Afterwards, it thinks for a while and then returns a generic "Windows couldn't connect" message.  Literally no details attached.

Comment: What errors or issues did it return while attempting to connect within linux?

Comment: this problem only happens on his specific device?